# Data access between .xmal and .cs in xamarin form

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

I have taken a label in .xmal file.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ListDemo.TableView">

<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="Above TableView"></Label>
    <TableView>
        <TableView.Root>
            <TableSection Title="Test">
                <EntryCell Label="EntryCell"></EntryCell>
                <TextCell Text="Test" Detail="Text Detail"></TextCell>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <BoxView Color="Red"></BoxView>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Receivename}"></Label>
                                <Label Text="News URL 1"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <BoxView x:Name="boxView" Color="Blue" ></BoxView>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </TableSection>
        </TableView.Root>
    </TableView>
</StackLayout>
```

I want to set the Label data from .cs file.

```
namespace ListDemo
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TableView : ContentPage
    {
        public TableView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

           public string Receivename = "Hello";
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know , how can I set the dynamic data of Label . What to write in .cs file .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can only bind to properties. So you would need:

```
public string Recievename { get; set; }
```

Second, you are setting this data in the constructor, when it should be within the scope of the actual class.

You can, however, set the value of the property in the constructor. Just not define it there.

Update per request:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class TableView : ContentPage
{
    public string Receivename { get; set; }

    public TableView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this; //Need to set data context as well, if not defined in XAML
        Receivename = "Hello";
    }
}
```

I also suggest you look more into binding, property notification, etc. This blog on xamarin should give you a hint: https://blog.xamarin.com/introduction-to-data-binding/

Comment: I am very new to xamarin. Can you please code this for me? I am very confuse  , where to write and what to write here to set the data

Comment: Does that stack panel and label exist in the 'TableView's XAML? Perhaps post more of your XAMLs contents.

Comment: yes I have tried . it shows me an error of saying. "datacontext does not exist in current context"

Comment: Sorry, I am coming from a WPF background, so it appears some things are different. It seems Xamarin forms using "BindingContext" instead of "DataContext"